# Uninstall Xmind Zen

Tags: 14.04

I have Xmind ZEN software installed in `/opt/Xmind ZEN` folder. How to remove this software?

Non of commands below helped:

```
sudo apt-get remove xen-hypervisor-amd64

sudo apt-get purge xen*
```

Both of commands finds nothing to remove

I suppose, deleting folder is not good idea. How to solve this problem?

Comment: It was obviously not installed with apt-get, so the solution is probably `sudo rm -r /opt/Xmind ZEN`.

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```bsh
sudo dpkg --remove xmind-vana
```

Comment: Also works in 18.04 - confirmed this is the correct package name here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238929